# MultiPointTouchArea in QT

Tags: c++, qt

wI use MultiPointTouchArea to design my own keyboard which can move with my finger.But there is a quetion that troubles me a few days.
In the Document of QT,it says that when we use MultiPointTouchArea in MultiPointTouchArea,we should have a onGestureStarted() to grab the TouchPoint that we need.
but when I run the code,here comes the problem.

```
 import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width:3600
    height:3600

    MultiPointTouchArea
    {

onGestureStarted: { gesture.grab();}




      anchors.fill:parent
        minimumTouchPoints: 8
        mouseEnabled: true
        id:test1
        Image {
                id: rocket
                fillMode: Image.TileHorizontally
                smooth: true
                //source: 'file:///home/v/Desktop/KeyBroad_1024.jpg'
            }
         touchPoints:[
                  TouchPoint{id:point1},
                  TouchPoint{id:point2},
                  TouchPoint{id:point3},
                  TouchPoint{id:point4},
                  TouchPoint{id:point5},
                  TouchPoint{id:point6},
                  TouchPoint{id:point7},
                  TouchPoint{id:point8}//,
                  //TouchPoint{id:point9},
                  //TouchPoint{id:point10}
             //function GAL(point1.x){}
         ]//fnction GAL(point1,point2){if(point1.x<point2.x) }
         Rectangle {
             width: 40; height: 40
             color: "blue"
             id:me11
             x: point1.x
             y: point1.y
             Text {
              text: qsTr("1")
             }}
             Rectangle {
                 width: 40; height: 40




                 color: "blue"
                 id:me12
                 x: point2.x
                 y: point2.y
                 Text {
                  text: qsTr("2")
                 }
                 MultiPointTouchArea{

                     anchors.fill:parent;
                     property color color_press: "lightgray"
                     property color color_release: "white"

                     onPressed: {
                         parent.color = color_press;
                         xPort.send(modifiersKey, message, 1);
                     }
                     onReleased: {
                         parent.color = color_release;
                         xPort.send(modifiersKey, message, 0);
                     }}
             }
             Rectangle {
                 width: 40; height: 40
                 color: "blue"
                 id:me13
                 x: point3.x
                 y: point3.y
                 Text {
                  text: qsTr("3")
                 }MultiPointTouchArea{

                     anchors.fill:parent;
                     property color color_press: "lightgray"
                     property color color_release: "white"

                     onPressed: {
                         parent.color = color_press;
                         xPort.send(modifiersKey, message, 1);
                     }
                     onReleased: {
                         parent.color = color_release;
                         xPort.send(modifiersKey, message, 0);
                     }}
             }
            Rectangle {
                 width: 40; height: 40
                 color: "blue"
                 id:me14
                 x: point4.x
                 y: point4.y
                 Text {
                  text: qsTr("4")
                 }MultiPointTouchArea{

                     anchors.fill:parent;
                     property color color_press: "lightgray"
                     property color color_release: "white"

                     onPressed: {
                         parent.color = color_press;
                         xPort.send(modifiersKey, message, 1);
                     }
                     onReleased: {
                         parent.color = color_release;
                         xPort.send(modifiersKey, message, 0);
                     }}}
                 Rectangle {
                     width: 40; height: 40
                     color: "blue"
                     id:me15
                     x: point5.x
                     y: point5.y
                     Text {
                      text: qsTr("5")
                     }
                     MultiPointTouchArea{

                         anchors.fill:parent;
                         property color color_press: "lightgray"
                         property color color_release: "white"

                         onPressed: {
                             parent.color = color_press;
                             xPort.send(modifiersKey, message, 1);
                         }
                         onReleased: {
                             parent.color = color_release;
                             xPort.send(modifiersKey, message, 0);
                         }} }
                 Rectangle {
                     width: 40; height: 40
                     color: "blue"
                     id:me16
                     x: point6.x
                     y: point6.y
                     Text {
                      text: qsTr("6")
                     }
                     MultiPointTouchArea{

                         anchors.fill:parent;
                         property color color_press: "lightgray"
                         property color color_release: "white"

                         onPressed: {
                             parent.color = color_press;
                             xPort.send(modifiersKey, message, 1);
                         }
                         onReleased: {
                             parent.color = color_release;
                             xPort.send(modifiersKey, message, 0);
                         }} }
                 Rectangle {
                     width: 40; height: 40
                     color: "blue"
                     id:me17
                     x: point7.x
                     y: point7.y
                     Text {
                      text: qsTr("7")
                     }
                     MultiPointTouchArea{

                         anchors.fill:parent;
                         property color color_press: "lightgray"
                         property color color_release: "white"

                         onPressed: {
                             parent.color = color_press;
                             xPort.send(modifiersKey, message, 1);
                         }
                         onReleased: {
                             parent.color = color_release;
                             xPort.send(modifiersKey, message, 0);
                         }}}
                 Rectangle {
                     width: 40; height: 40
                     color: "blue"
                     id:me18
                     x: point8.x
                     y: point8.y
                     Text {
                      text: qsTr("8")
                     }
                     MultiPointTouchArea{

                         anchors.fill:parent;
                         property color color_press: "lightgray"
                         property color color_release: "white"

                         onPressed: {
                             parent.color = color_press;
                             xPort.send(modifiersKey, message, 1);
                         }
                         onReleased: {
                             parent.color = color_release;
                             xPort.send(modifiersKey, message, 0);
                         }}}

}
}
```

It can not fetch figers as I set.
For example,I put fingers by left hand's little finger to left hand's forefinger,and right hand's forefinger to little finger.It shall be 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8 in the window.But when minimumTouchPoints = 8,sometimes it didn't work,and sometimes it work in a wrong way(like 5-2-3-4-1-6-7-8).
I need MultiPoint to creat button,so here comes the questions.
1、what can I do ?
2、Is there other way to fulfill my aim :Creat a keyborad,then it can work as a real keyboard.
Thanks for your Answer.